# The covariance value is greater than 1 in Amos

Tags: amos

I would like to ask about the path analysis I ran using Amos, the value of the covariance between two latent variables was greater than 1, is it acceptable? if not how can I fix it?[image]

Comment: Covariance isn't bounded above by 1; it is not like correlation in that respect. The units of covariance are the units of the two variables multiplied together and so values above 1 are entirely possible.

Comment: Note that these are the errors e9--e8 that are correlated in the above picture (probably to improve model fit), most of the correlation between the latent variables VWM and AWM  comes from their shared connection with PS.